# Checking element in ArrayList between two double quotes

Tags: java, arraylist, lexer

I'm writing a primitive version of programming language reader in Java for custom language that I made and I want to find out easiest way to print content of element from ArrayList that is located between two elements of double quotes. Here is source code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PrimitiveCompiler {

    public static ArrayList<String> toks = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String content = readFile("C:\\program.txt");

        tokenize(content);
    }

    public static String readFile(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File f = new File(filePath);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(f);

        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            b.append(input.nextLine());
        }

        input.close();

        return b.toString();
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> tokenize(String fContent) {
        int i = 0;
        String tok = "";

        String contents = fContent.replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\t", "");

        for(int a = 0; a <= contents.length() - 1; a++) {
            tok += contents.charAt(a);
            i = a;

            if(tokenFinderEquals(tok, "WRITE")) {
                toks.add("WRITE");
                tok = "";
            }
        }

        System.out.println(toks);

        return null;

        }

    public static boolean tokenFinderEquals(String s1, String s2) {
        if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Content of text file right now is just *WRITE* and it succesfully finds it and add it to *ArrayList*. What I want to do is to count double quotes and when two double quotes are found in *ArrayList* to print out every element between them. Is it posibble or there's another, easier way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need some kind of state to keep track of whether or not you're inside of a quote. For example:

```
boolean inQuote = false;
for (int a = 0; a <= contents.length() - 1; a++) {
  char c = contents.charAt(a);
  if (c == '"') {
    // Found a quote character. Are we at the beginning or the end?
    if (!inQuote) {
      // Start of a quoted string.
      inQuote = true;
    } else {
      // End of a quoted string.
      inQuote = false;
      toks.add(tok);
      tok = "";
    }
    // Either way, we don't add the quote char to `tok`.
  } else {
    tok += c;
    if (!inQuote && tokenFinderEquals(tok, "WRITE") {
      // Only look for "WRITE" when outside of a quoted string.
      toks.add(tok);
      tok = "";
    }
  }
}
```

Using a simple loop like this can start to get tough as you add more cases, though. You may want to look into writing a [recursive descent parser](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/javanotes5.0.1/c9/s5.html).